# What are the restrictions on the weights of a linear combination of a random sample as an unbiased estimator of E(X)

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, expected-value

I would like to find the proof of the following:

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be a random sample of $X$ and $a_1,...,a_n$ real numbers.

If $\sum_{i=1}^n a_iX_i$ is an unbiased estimator of $E(X)$ then $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 1$

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Do you know the definition of an unbiased estimator?

Comment: As previous commenter said, this is an application of unbiased estimator definition. Take expected value of the sum and equate it to $\mathbb{E}[X]$, conclusion then follows immediately from linearity of expectations.

Comment: I think I do know the definition.  Let's say Z is the estimator and  u is the parameter we are trying to estimate.  Then if Z is unbiased E(Z) = u.  Right? In this case I think E($sum_{i=1}^n a_iX_i$) has to equal E(X). I was trying to see if looking at $ \int...\int a_1X_1 + ...+a_nX_n f_{x_1,.  x_n}(x_1, ..., x_n) dx_1 ...dx_n = E(X) $would lead to the solution, but I can't see how you jump to the conclusion that $sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 1$

Comment: $E\left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_iX_i\right] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_iE\left[X_i\right] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i E[X]$ so if this is $E[X]\not =0$ then $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n a_i =1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to know two things here:

1. The expectation is linear meaning that $\operatorname E[aX+bY]=a\operatorname EX+b\operatorname EY$.
2. If $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ is a random sample of $X$, then $\operatorname EX=\operatorname EX_1=\operatorname EX_2=\ldots=\operatorname EX_n$.

Using these two facts, we can show that $\sum_{i=1}^na_i$ has to be equal to $1$ if the estimator is unbiased.

I hope this is helpful and you can continue from here.

Comment: That helps thanks. So E($a_1X_1 + ... + a_nX_n$) = $a_1$E($X_1$) + ...+ $a_n$E($X_n$). Since E($X_i$) = E(X) then E(X)($sum_{i=1}^n a_i$) = E(X) and $sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 1$